# How to protect pages in Next.js 13 App router client side pages and server side

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

As i have seen in different places to protect the pages someone is using middelware.js to protect the pages (client side and server side ) and someone is using `useSession` hook for client side page  and `getServerSession` for server side pages. I have a confusion which one is correct way and recommended way in `nextjs 13`

1. One way to Protect pages

client side

```
'use client'

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

const ClientProtectPage = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      redirect('/signin?callbackUrl=/protected/client')
    }
  })

  return (
    <section className='py-24'>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>
          This is a <span className='text-emerald-500'>client-side</span>{' '}
          protected page
        </h1>
        <h2 className='mt-4 font-medium'>You are logged in as:</h2>
        <p className='mt-4'>{session?.user?.name}</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ClientProtectPage





- server side protected page

 import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
        import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
        import { authOptions } from '../../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route'
        
        const ServerProtectedPage = async () => {
          const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
        
          if (!session) {
            redirect('/signin?callbackUrl=/protected/server')
          }
        
          return (
            <section className='py-24'>
              <div className='container'>
                <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>
                  This is a <span className='text-emerald-500'>server-side</span>{' '}
                  protected page
                </h1>
                <h2 className='mt-4 font-medium'>You are logged in as:</h2>
                <p className='mt-4'>{session?.user?.name}</p>
              </div>
            </section>
          )
        }
        export default ServerProtectedPage




2. second way to protect pages using middelware

    import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"
    import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"
    import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
    
    export default withAuth(
      async function middleware(req) {
        const token = await getToken({ req })
        const isAuth = !!token
        const isAuthPage =
          req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") ||
          req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/register")
    
        if (isAuthPage) {
          if (isAuth) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url))
          }
    
          return null
        }
    
        if (!isAuth) {
          let from = req.nextUrl.pathname;
          if (req.nextUrl.search) {
            from += req.nextUrl.search;
          }
    
          return NextResponse.redirect(
            new URL(`/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(from)}`, req.url)
          );
        }
      },
      {
        callbacks: {
          async authorized() {
            // This is a work-around for handling redirect on auth pages.
            // We return true here so that the middleware function above
            // is always called.
            return true
          },
        },
      }
    )
    
    export const config = {
      matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/editor/:path*", "/login", "/register"],
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I went down the rabbit hole just the other day of figuring this out. I wanted auth to be checked server-side and persisted client-side, so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRLjoT4r-jc&ab_channel=JackHerrington) to learn how to use server rendered pages in Next.js along with Redux to share the state from server to client. I made my root [layout.tsx](https://github.com/architect-team/twitter-clone/blob/db32bce58e4e94a5d0f367726dd81d2f7d5b5ad6/app/layout.tsx) file async that loads the auth data server side, and then passed the auth data to my [redux provider](https://github.com/architect-team/twitter-clone/blob/db32bce58e4e94a5d0f367726dd81d2f7d5b5ad6/app/provider.tsx) so that it can be loaded client-side.

Whether or not this is the "correct" implementation or even the recommended one I couldn't tell you. How you manage state sometimes depends on the specific use case. In my case, auth was so important to the entire app that I decided it warranted being loaded server-side instead of showing a global loading page.